# LoginAttempCount in appsettings.json file

Tags: appsettings

In .NET core project why we use LoginAttempCount in appsettings.json file. what is its purpose to use.
"LoginAttempCount": "3",
This is used in my project
anyone can tell me?

Comment: You can put any custom configuration in your appsettings file and map it to a custom model you created, this setting you mentioned probably isn't a general .NET setting, so there is no way of telling what this (probably) custom setting is used for in your app. Based on it's name I would guess your app blocks users after three failed login attempts. Try searching for the setting's name (LoginAttempCount) in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

These are custom settings. In core you have to mention your own properties which you can used across the application. The purpose of these settings is to make it constant and you can change it only single point of change which is very easy to maintained.